# Submit the value of a <p> element when an html form is submitted

Tags: forms, post

I have this code: `<p class = "foo">Text</p>`

And I also have a form: `<form action = "XXX.php" method = post></form>`

However, how can I get the value of the `<p>` when I submit it, as the `<p>` element can be changed.

So what I mean is to be able to post the value of the `<p>` when the user submits the form, and to be able to access it from that php file with: `$_POST['foo'];`

Thanks, I have tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Event though its old wouldn't it make sense to leave the p, use jquery to take the p's text, and set it tot he value of a hidden input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to make it an input with readonly enabled, and style to to look like a `<p>`. It's better then trying to add it to the POST parameters with JavaScript.

**[Here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/cEVK7/)**. I bet it could still be improved with a few extra CSS quirks, experiment a bit.

Comment: Styling something to look like a <p> does not answer this question. The question asks how to submit the value of <p> and we have to assume the scenario requires <p> and cannot be removed.

Comment: @RyanBayne The asker marked this answer as correct, so clearly it was an option, but even if not, this isn't the only answer. Also note that question and the answer are from 2011.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use Javascript for that

A jQuery function that will work

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    var value = $("p").html();

    // If foo already exists
    if( $("[name=foo]").length > 0 )
    {
        $("[name=foo]").val(value);
    } 
    else
    {
         var input = $("<input />", { name : "foo", 
                                      value : value , 
                                      type : "hidden" });
         $(this).append(input);
    }

});
```

Comment: This is the true solution that answers the question - strictly. The hidden input has to be considered though.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<input type="hidden" value="something" name="something" id="something" />
```

and when you change inner html of `<p>` change the value of hidden input.

Comment: to synch the changes, is it possible to only use css?

Comment: Acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is set the value of a hidden form field when you change the contents of your `<p>`.

Alternatively, you can get its contents and post with JavaScript.

Comment: to synch the changes, is it possible to only use css?

Comment: No. What does CSS have to do with any of this?

Comment: excuse me, i meant, html

Comment: Sure, you could add a hidden input to your form when you generate the HTML in the first place... but otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

1. For text you **need** to use input field:

   `<input type="text"/>`
2. Form fields should must have an `id`:

   `<input type="text" id="pewpew" class="foo"/>`

I would go with:

`<input type="text" id="pewpew" class="foo" value="default text goes here"/>`

OR

Go with different workarounds, like setting form's hidden elements on the fly, etc.

Comment: He does not **need** an input fields.

Comment: `<textarea>` is input field too :)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean he **needs** it :) It's perfectly acceptable to use JavaScript to alter the POST request. an input field is an **easier** solution. Not a **mandatory** one. :P

Comment: Well, that's why I mentioned *OR*. You **need** it if you don't use JS :) I've got your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden field on the fly and set its value on form submit. Like this:

```
<form id="form" action="/somewhere" method="post">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.onsubmit = function()
  {
    var p = this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    if (!document.getElementById('pval'))
    {
      var pinput = document.createElement('input');
      pinput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      pinput.setAttribute('id', 'pval');
      pinput.setAttribute('name', 'p');
      this.appendChild(pinput);
    }

    document.getElementById('pval').value = p.innerHTML;

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Works, i've tested.