# How do I use Javascript to access the contents of an HTML p tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 php pages

- home.php
- about.php

I have 1 Javascript page, which I called javascript from home.php.

I want to access the value of the p tag in `about.php`.

**home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="submit" onclick='myfunction()'>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>

function myfunction()
{

}

</script>
```

**about.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
</head>
<body>
    <p id='demo'>i want to access this value in javascript function</p>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now also tell what is your question

Comment: i  want to access the value of p tag in myfunction

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something in pure javascript like:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='change the p tag value';
</script>
```

Comment: i think you are getting me wrong about.php is a different page so the id property is not accesable

Answer (score 1):

```
var pTag = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
```

The variable pTag will now hold the value(text) of your "demo" tag,
ready for you to do what you wish with it.

**EDIT:**

Using Javascript, set the value of a hidden form field when you change the contents of your

tag.
Then pass the values using php, like below...

home.php:

```
<form action="about.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="demo" id="demo" />
    <p id="pDemo"> </p>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Then in about.php:

```
<p id='demo'>
<?php
    $demo= $_GET['demo'];
    //use your variable "demo'
?>
</p>
```

This link should help, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156614/submit-the-value-of-a-p-element-when-an-html-form-is-submitted).

Comment: i think you are getting me wrong about.php is a different page so the id property is not accesable

Comment: PHP is server side whilst Javascript is client side, try rephrasing your question then maybe, we seem to have all misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunction(){   
  var val= document.getElementById('demo').textContent;
  alert(val);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f4z7sufw/)

Comment: frnds i think you all are getting me wrong about.php is a different page so the id property is not accesable

Comment: Ohk..got it..Its more clear now..You can use ajax here..This link will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899047/how-to-use-javascript-to-access-another-pages-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can  use ajax or you can use load of jquery.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bAdd").load("about.php",function(response,status,xhr){// use if less data to load

        var pTag = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
        alert(pTag);
    });

    });


</script>

    <input type="hidden" id="bAdd"  value="">
```